# Set operations: should only work with sets, but works with dict_keys?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, set

The [documentation for set operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.copy) says:

> Note, the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(),
> difference(), symmetric_difference(), issubset(), and issuperset()
> methods will accept any iterable as an argument. In contrast, their
> operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets. This
> precludes error-prone constructions like `set('abc') & 'cbs'` in favor
> of the more readable `set('abc').intersection('cbs')`.

Testing this with the following experiment:

```py
# Python 3.10.2 (main, Jan 15 2022, 19:56:27) [GCC 11.1.0] on linux

>>> set('ab') & set('ac')
{'a'}
# works, as expected

>>> set('ab') & 'ac'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'str'
# doesn't work, as expected

>>> set('ab') & list('ac')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'list'
# doesn't work, as expected

>>> set('ab') & iter('ac')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'str_iterator'
# doesn't work, as expected

>>> set('ab') & dict(zip('ac', 'ac')).keys()
{'a'}
# works??

>>> type({}.keys())
<class 'dict_keys'>

>>> isinstance({}.keys(), (set, frozenset))
False
```

So, here is the paradox:

- `set` operator `&` works with `dict_keys` objects;
- The documentation says it should only work with sets;
- `dict_keys` objects are not sets.

Why does set operator `&` work with dict_keys objects? Are there other types that it works with? How can I find a list of these types?

Comment: PEP 3106 could be relevant

Comment: @oda Thanks! I'm reading it now. This paragraph sounds like an answer: *"The objects returned by .keys() and .items() are fully interoperable with instances of the built-in set and frozenset types; for example: `set(d.keys()) == d.keys()` is guaranteed to be True (except when d is being modified simultaneously by another thread)."*

Comment: Indeed. Dictionary keys must be hashable and a set is an unordered collection of unique hashable objects so it makes sense that dictionary keys can behave like a set. Unfortunately the PEP does not answer your other questions regarding whether other types work with it or if you can get a list of these types.

Comment: Related: [When can dict_values views be set-like (and why)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55940027/674039)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not a complete answer, but `dict_keys` are instances of [`collections.abc.Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set):

```
from collections.abc import Set
k = dict(zip('ac', 'ac')).keys()
print(isinstance(k, Set))  # -> True
```

Comment: Awesome! I really didn't know that. I just tested the following two lines of code: `a = dict(zip(range(10000000), range(10000000)))` (takes several seconds); then `9999999 in a.keys()` (instantaneous). This seems to confirm that `dict_keys` behaves like a set.

Comment: if i remember correctly, the first implementation of `set`s in python were basically `dict`s without values. now the implementations differ (`dict`s keep insertion order - `set`s don't).

Answer (score 1):

This section of the docs is referring to what the `set`/`frozenset` types support. Indeed, `set` does not support the comparison with `dict_keys` instances, and it correctly returns [`NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented) to indicate this operation is unsupported:

```
>>> left = set('ab')
>>> right = dict(zip('ac', 'ac')).keys()
>>> left.__and__(right)
NotImplemented
```

This return value indicates that Python should attempt the [reflected operation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rand__) with the other operand, to see if that is supported. And it succeeds:

```
>>> right.__rand__(left)
{'a'}
```

If *both* `type(left).__and__` and `type(right).__rand__` are returning `NotImplemented`, then you will see a `TypeError` exception.

So, there is no paradox, just a subtlety in the datamodel: after `set` opts out, the `dict_keys` type is afforded the chance to handle the binary operation from the right-hand side.